# How do I show/hide two divs with one link?

Tags: jquery

I've stripped out some tag bloat for the sake of readability.  This code works perfectly for clicking on an image and opening a div (utilizing an id).

```
<script>src="jquery-1.5.2.js"</script>
<style>.toggle {display:none}</style>

<script>
  $(window).load(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
      var myelement = $(this).attr("href")
      $(myelement).slideToggle("fast");
      $(".toggle:visible").not(myelement).hide();
    });
  });
</script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#box1"><img src="ButtonA.png"/></a></td>
    <td><a href="#box2"><img src="ButtonB.png"/></a></td>
    <td><a href="#box3"><img src="ButtonC.png"/></a></td>
    <td><a href="#box4"><img src="ButtonD.png"/></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="toggle" id="box1">Box 1</div>
<div class="toggle" id="box2">Box 2</div>
<div class="toggle" id="box3">Box 3</div>
<div class="toggle" id="box4">Box 4</div>
```

All I want to do is have everything work the way it currently does, but be able to open 2 divs at the same time.

Here is an example of what I've tried but DOES NOT work.

```
<script>src="jquery-1.5.2.js"</script>
<style>.toggle {display:none}</style>

<script>
  $(window).load(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
      var myelement = $(this).attr("href")
      $(myelement).slideToggle("fast");
      $(".toggle:visible").not(myelement).hide();
    });
  });
</script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#box1"><img src="ButtonA.png"/></a></td>
    <td><a href="#box2"><img src="ButtonB.png"/></a></td>
    <td><a href="#box3"><img src="ButtonC.png"/></a></td>
    <td><a href="#box4"><img src="ButtonD.png"/></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="toggle" id="box1">Box 1</div>
<div class="toggle" id="box1">My New Additional Box</div>
<div class="toggle" id="box2">Box 2</div>
<div class="toggle" id="box3">Box 3</div>
<div class="toggle" id="box4">Box 4</div>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique. You have two divs with the same id `box1`

Comment: While this statement is true, it does not give me a solution.  Still, thank you for posting.  I did not know ID's needed to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot duplicate an `id` in the HTML. So better give `class` for this special case:

```
<div class="toggle box" id="box1" class="same-box-1">Box 1</div>
<div class="toggle box" id="box5" class="same-box-1">My New Additional Box</div>
```

And change your `<a>` like:

```
<a href=".same-box-1" class="same-box"><img src="ButtonA.png"/></a>
```

In the JavaScript:

```
$("a").click(function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass("same-box")) {
    $($(this).attr("href")).slideDown();
    return false;
  }
});
```

> ***Note:*** And please update jQuery to the latest or somewhat decent version (1.9+).

**Updated Working Solution**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("a").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("same-box")) {
      $(".toggle:visible").slideUp();
      $($(this).attr("href")).slideDown();
      return false;
    }
    var myelement = $(this).attr("href");
    $(myelement).slideToggle("fast");
    $(".toggle:visible").not(myelement).slideUp();
  });
});
```

```css
.toggle { display: none; } 
.same-box-1 { display: none; }
.same-box-2 { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" align="center">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <a href=".same-box-1" class="same-box"><img src="http://goo.gl/wV8dmU" alt=""/></a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="#box2"><img src="http://goo.gl/wV8dmU" alt=""/></a></td>
      <td><a href="#box3"><img src="http://goo.gl/wV8dmU" alt=""/></a></td>
      <td><a href="#box4"><img src="http://goo.gl/wV8dmU" alt=""/></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="same-box-1 toggle" id="box1">Box 1</div>
<div class="same-box-1 toggle" id="box5">My New Additional Box</div>
<div class="same-box-2 toggle" id="box2">Box 2</div>
<div class="same-box-2 toggle" id="box3">Box 3</div>
<div class="same-box-2 toggle" id="box4">Box 4</div>
```

Since the OP doesn't even know how to use JSBin / JSFiddle / Writing JavaScripts, I have created the working snippet, and I hope they can copy and paste without mistake.

Comment: <a href=".same-box-1" 
This just causes the link to open .same-box-1 in the browser

Comment: @ideaguy1974 No way, if you have correctly copied, coz I have given `return false;`, which will not allow the browser to navigate with the link. Please kindly check.

Comment: Do you see any errors with this?

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
 $("a").click(function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass("same-box")) {
    $($(this).attr("href")).slideDown();
    return false;
  }
});
</script>

Comment: Use `$(document).ready(function () {})` instead of what you are using.

Comment: @ideaguy1974 Please talk like a developer. **Where have you added a reference to jQuery?** And `<script...` is invalid in JavaScript. Don't you know that it is HTML? And you haven't added the `same-box` class!!!

Comment: @ideaguy1974 You there?

Comment: @ideaguy1974 Please learn to use jsfiddle, else don't use it. It is only for developers, not for newbies. If in doubt, use JSBin.

Comment: Sorry, I'm sure it's frustrating helping a "newbie"...  I've updated my code: https://jsfiddle.net/ideaguy1974/5q7Lwm3m/ and it's giving me the 2 divs for 1 link but we've lost the toggle effect I originally had. I need the 2 divs that show to hide when the button is clicked again, or another button is clicked.  Thank you for your help thus far.

Comment: @ideaguy1974 Understand, it's okay as long as you reply quickly. You didn't put your original code now.

Comment: @ideaguy1974 Sorry if I am rude.

Comment: @ideaguy1974 Also in my answer, refresh and check by clicking on Run Code Snippet and see if it works. **Please reply!**

Comment: sorry, I'm an old man by your standards (41) can't go as fast as you youngins...  It's amazing what you did.  I see it working.  The only thing is when I click the button (and it opens) if I click the same button again, it closes, but then it opens right back up again on it's own... not really a toggle but a reset.

Comment: i am walking away from my machine for the day.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @ideaguy1974 Sorry sir, I didn't know that. I am sorry if I had been rude or something. When you come back, I will have it fixed. Please consider accepting the answer. Thanks. `:)`